# Expression did not evaluate to a constant despite using a dynamic array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, msbuild, jetbrains-ide

I have a program which asks the user to input the amount of courses they are taking. It takes this in as a string so it can check if the input is an integer or not. Then stoi is used to convert to an int and an array is made so it can contain all the course names. The integer variable is the length of this array. My issue is that MSBuild is telling me expression does not evaluate to a constant. The link below told me to use a dynamic array instead which is what I changed it to but I am still having the same exact issue.

[expression did not evaluate to a constant- c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423502/expression-did-not-evaluate-to-a-constant-c)

Methods.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Variables
int number_of_course_taken;

// Arrays
std::string* course_names = new std::string[number_of_course_taken];


// Methods
void course_input(std::string course_names[number_of_course_taken]);
```

main.cpp snippet

```
   // Taking amount of courses user is enrolled in
string courses = "";
int i = 0;
int count = 0;
while (true)
{
    // test condition to check for int status works for strings but doubles trick the system.
    cout << "How many courses do you want to take?\n If this is not the first time you are seeing this prompt,\n that means you entered a faulty input. Enter a number \n between 1 and 8.";
    cin >> courses;

    // Iteratres to every character checking if it is a digit or not
    // this deduces whether user inputted integer or something else
    for (i = 0; i < courses.length(); i++) 
    {
        if (isdigit(courses[i]) == false) 
        {
            count=1;
            break;
        }
        else
            count=0;
 
    } if(count==0)
    {
        cout << "Number inputted is an Integer\n";
        int temp = std::stoi(courses);
        number_of_course_taken = temp;
        if (number_of_course_taken >= 1 && number_of_course_taken <= 8)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    else
        cout << "Number inputted is not an integer\n";
}
void course_input(string course_names[number_of_course_taken]);
```

Methods.cpp

```
#include "methods.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Method that will take user input and store each into an array
void course_input(string course_names[number_of_course_taken])
{
    string course_name_input;
    int j = 0;
    // Run until user enters amount that coresponds with number of courses
    while (j!= number_of_course_taken)
    {
        j = j + 1;
        // error checking to make sure user inputs course name less than 20
        while (true)
        {
            cout << "Enter a course name. It must be greater than 0 characters and less than 20 characters.\n";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin,course_name_input);
            if (course_name_input.length() > 20 || course_name_input.length() <= 0)
            {
                cout << "You entered a course that either has 0 characters or more than 20. Please try again\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "The course name fits the criteria.\n";
                course_names[j] = course_name_input;
                cout << "For testing purposes: " << course_names;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output message and screenshot

```
  methods.h(13, 44): [C2131] expression did not evaluate to a constant
  methods.h(13, 44): [] see usage of 'number_of_course_taken'
  HonorRollProcedural.cpp(83, 43): [C2131] expression did not evaluate to a constant
  HonorRollProcedural.cpp(83, 43): [] see usage of 'number_of_course_taken'
  methods.h(13, 44): [C2131] expression did not evaluate to a constant
  methods.h(13, 44): [] see usage of 'number_of_course_taken'
  methods.cpp(7, 39): [C2131] expression did not evaluate to a constant
  methods.cpp(7, 39): [] see usage of 'number_of_course_taken'
  methods.cpp(28, 52): [C3863] array type 'std::string [number_of_course_taken]' is not assignable
```

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Comment: This is not the way how it works. `std::string* course_names = new std::string[number_of_course_taken];` is resolved when compiled. At this time, the compiler cannot know in any way what value will be given at run-time. You have to move the allocation (the right-hand side) into a body of a function at a point when the input has been done and the value is known at run-time. Btw. using a dynamic array is a bad idea. Please, have a look for [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (the better "dynamic array" of C++).

Comment: @Scheff I have decided to use vectors instead because as you mentioned they are better. How would I use the vector in a function because I need to run a method to input the course names into the vector.

Comment: Two options: a) `std::vector<std::string>` is the return type of your function. (`std::vector` provides an assignment operator.) b) You provide an argument `std::vector<std::string>&` to provide the reference to an outside instance which is filled by the function. Concerning a): Yes, you can assign a vector, and no, this doesn't work with C arrays (neither in C nor in C++.) There were many reasons to invent `std::vector`, and the assign operator was only one of them. ;-)